# Is there a way to add customised names to the error message in R shiny application

Tags: r

With the below code i was able to remove error message in my R shiny application. But is there a way to add customized name to the error message like " No Purchase history "

Below is the code to remove error message

```
tags$head(tags$style(".shiny-output-error{visibility: hidden;}"))
```

Comment: not shiny specific but `tryCatch`: http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912

Comment: I once used `tryCatch` with `showNotification("This is displayed", duration = 2, closeButton = TRUE, type = "error")` which worked well for me.

Comment: May I know where in shiny you declared ths? Also may I  know what is duration = 2?

Comment: I put this on `observeEvent(input$someInput,{ tryCatch(sometest, error = function(e){ show Notification(...)})})` in the server file of the shiny app. duration specifies the duration of the Popup window in seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Will check on this

Answer (score 0):

Within your plot function, you can put something like this:

```
shiny::validate(
            need((nrow(DataSet()) != 0), "No purchase history")
          )
```

You can have as many validate functions that you need and make them as complicated as you need to help the user troubleshoot.

Based on OP comments:

```
output$table <- DT::renderDT(

    shiny::validate(
        need(input$Date[2] > input$Date[1], "Invalid Dates"),
        need((nrow(data2()) != 0), "No purchase history")
    )

    datatable(data2())

)
```

Comment: Thanks. But in case I need to put another messge like. If ````input$Date[2] > input$Date[1]````, it should be ````"Invalid dates"````

Comment: Actually the output is a DTtable . ````output$table <- DT::renderDT(
    datatable(data2()
    )````

Comment: Thanks. I tried but the datatable is not displayed at all